# attempted to read or write protected memory - dllimport

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged

I'm having a problem trying to import a c++ dll into c#

I always get the error "attempted to read or write protected memory" when I call the constructor of the dll class. I've been locking in other solutions for the same answer but I couldn't found solution.

I decided to use a simple function to discard that the error came from the c++ part but I'm having the same problem...

Here is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"

simple_dll::simple_dll(int num) : numero(num) {}

int simple_dll::getNumero() {
    return this->numero;
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

// void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);
class DLL_EXPORT simple_dll {
    public:
        DLL_EXPORT simple_dll(int num);
        DLL_EXPORT int getNumero();
        int numero;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

And the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

namespace prueba_dll_VS 
{
    unsafe class Program
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("simple_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "_ZN10simple_dllC2Ei")]
        private static extern System.IntPtr simple_dll(int num);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("simple_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "_ZN10simple_dll9getNumeroEv")]
        private static extern int getNumero(System.IntPtr hObject);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IntPtr ptr_simple_dll = simple_dll(4); //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR RAISES
            int hora = getNumero(ptr_simple_dll);
            Console.WriteLine(hora);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting mad, this can't be so difficult.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you must treat your constructor like a function/method? You are not using `new` on `simple_dll` constructor, after all...

Comment: Yeah, that too. If you want to really construct, you'd need to use AllocCoTaskMem() with the size of the object and *then* call the constructor on it... Much easier to export a static method that does the `new` (and another one, static or not, that does the `delete`).

Comment: I'm following this example:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ad74be1-8152-4bb4-8ced-3a400c04182d/dll-import-in-c maybe is not the rigth thing to do

Comment: Pinvoking an instance method on a C++ class is very difficult to get right, the constructor and destructor as well as the object size are strong implementation details of the C++ compiler.  Using g++ certainly doesn't make it easier, there's no standard ABI for C++ compilers.  Only static method can work well, for instance methods you should write a wrapper in the C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the calling convention. In the current form, the functions are exported in `thiscall`, but the `DllImport` attribute defaults to `stdcall` (or `cdecl` on smartphones).

Comment: and how should I fix that? I've changed thee callingconvention to both in the [dllimport] but the result is the same...

Comment: I'm not sure. I never export native C++ classes (let alone across language boundaries), only functions and COM interfaces...